# How to deserialize HttpHeaders in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I am implementing a caching system using redis with spring cloud gateway which uses netty.

I have my cached body model below

```
public class CachedResponse {
        HttpStatus httpStatus;
        HttpHeaders headers;
        byte[] body;    
    }
```

Everything seems to be working until deserialization. I cant seem to deserialize the headers field. i get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no default no-arguments constructor found.
```

Also, spring is not using my imported HttpHeaders (*org.springframework.http*) but uses from *io.netty.handler.codec.http* which is an abstract class.

Below is my configured objectmapper bean:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE);
    return mapper;
}
```

The question now is how do i get httpheaders to be deserialized ?
Thanks in advance.

The json payload which is of type CachedResponse (class above) looks like this:

```
{"@class":"com.microfinanceBank.apigateway.model.CachedResponse","httpStatus":"OK","headers":{"@class":"org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders","transfer-encoding":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["chunked"]],"Vary":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers"]],"X-Content-Type-Options":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["nosniff"]],"X-XSS-Protection":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["1; mode=block"]],"Cache-Control":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"]],"Pragma":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["no-cache"]],"Expires":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["0"]],"X-Frame-Options":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["DENY"]],"Content-Type":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["application/json"]],"Date":["io.netty.handler.codec.HeadersUtils$1",["Wed, 28 Sep 2022 23:17:42 GMT"]]},"body":"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"}
```

Comment: Can you add an example `JSON` payload you want to deserialise?

Comment: @MichałZiober please do check, i have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: The class is actually a `HttpHeaders` from Spring (check your logging output). The entires in there are however all from some netty dependency. Before caching you probably want to convert from that to a simple `MultiValueMap<String, String>` instead of the typed stuff you have now.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks worked out. God bless you